# Linking XCode Project to MySQL server (login)

Tags: ios, mysql, xcode

I am trying to connect my Xcode project to a MySQL database with login id and password. Does anyone have a sample code to do this? Should i write the code for the connection to the database in the appDelegate? Also, will this layout work on my storyboard? Thanks for the help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, remote mysql connection is not a good way for data access. This is unsecure and old.

Instead of this, you can create a web service with any language you want, in this web service, create mysql connection locally and make necessary operation in this web service. (Ex.receive post data, connect to db, return some result in json or xml).

You can create a connection class to web service in Swift or Objective C file.
Set your header values and get/post/patch/delete parameters and send to your web service.

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks! this helps a lot ö-ö